# Windows 8 right-click menu where start button used to be isn't working

Tags: windows-8

The so-called "power menu" as some call it - the one you get if you right-click in the far bottom left corner of the desktop - isn't working on one of my computers. The menu comes up, but no options on it actually do anything except "Run". When I click on anything, be it Control Panel, Task Manager.... whatever; nothing happens. Not sure how to approach this.

What could very likely have at least something to do with it is that Windows 8 was installed on this desktop through an in-place upgrade from Windows 7 Pro. Normally I shy away from doing upgrades as opposed to formatting, but I couldn't get around it this time due to all the stuff I had on the drive with nowhere to back it up.

Everything else seems to work perfectly fine (so far as I can see at the moment) except this. Any ideas as to why it's not behaving?

Comment: The Power Menu works fine with an in-place OS upgrade, so it's something specific to your install. Try `sfc /scannow` from an elevated command prompt and see if it fixes anything. If it doesn't, disable any programs (using msconfig or [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)) that load at startup and may be interfering. Finally, go to `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX` and check if the Power Menu shortcuts work properly when executed directly.

Comment: SFC is scanning now - but I checked those shortcuts, and they do work properly on their own. I also noticed that sometimes clicking on one of the options that does nothing actually restores a minimized window, but there seems to be no discernible pattern for me to figure out why.

Comment: Nope - no problems found with SFC

Comment: Are you on a domain? Could group policy be preventing these items?

Comment: Nah - this is a home computer. Not on a domain.